# omniauth (google_apps) Request phase initiated. blocking my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I just implement Omniauth+Devise to signin using Google Apps, but when doing the request and the "Request phase initiated" my app get blocked, i tried a request in another window and it didnt execute untill the "Request Phase" was over, several secods later.
im using omniauth-openid, omniauth-google-apps and Devise gems.